# Send a index.html file when server is created

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want a file like `index.html` to be loaded when the server is created. When I execute the `server.js` using node, I send a response as text like this `res.end("text")`. But I want the `index.html` to load.

I tried to load it using `sendFile()` in `app.get('/getFile')` but when I type in the address bar, I get the `text` for all the urls..even for `localhost:3000/getFile`.

This is my server.js:

```
    (function(){

var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

// app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'));

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.end("text");

});

server.listen('3000');
console.log("Server is listening");

app.get('/getFile',function(request,response){
    // response.end('shi');
    response.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
})
})();
```

Comment: If you're using `express` you should place your static files in the static folder. So you don't need to *preload* any html file, and write the code to send back to clients.

Comment: Maybe it's trivial, but in your code sample the `/getFile` handler send back *first.html* and not *index.html* as you wrote in your question.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini. can you please explain how to send the file to clients. I'm trying to send using the `sendFile()` but it shows the same `text`. I read that the content inside `createServer()` is executed every time a request is sent to server. So maybe thats why it's not showing the html file. This doesn't really seem to be it but I just want to make sure.  And yeah it's `first.html` that I'm actually sending. I said `index.html` so others can understand that I want it to be shown first

Comment: sorry I'm confused, you want to send back the *index.html* file, and that is waht you got in the code when you call the url '/getFile'. But as you are using express you should just put your html files in the static folder, and pass this to express app as described in the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). As it look like you just need to serve a static file, not something dynamically build on request.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini. thanks. i got your point.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini. When I server the static file using `app.use(express.static())`, the angularjs and other javascript files are not being executed.  When I click the button in the html nothing happens and I dont see any error in the console either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

I just made a folder and wrote the following code and I have checked that this is working.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/indexz.html');
});

app.listen(1339);
console.log('Open this link http://localhost:1337');
```

**Steps**

1 Copy the code given above in a new folder and name it whatever you want, name the file `server.js`

2 go to your cmd and propagate to location of your code and now `npm install express`

3 now type `node server` on console

4 open the link that is there on the console.

> Note : Make sure there is folder name public and there is a file named
>   indexz.html in there.

### [image: Directory Arrangement]

**Edited**

> Regarding proper client side files arrangement

You will have to keep all your files in public folder, first of all and attach them accordingly in your html document.

Example

```
<!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
<link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

and then within public folder you'll have folders named js and css and in root of the public folder your html files.

Comment: thanks. I tried it before but I keep getting `res.sendFile()` is not a function.

Comment: @Nobody in separate file just try this. http://pastebin.com/jbYUYZNs and make sure that express is installed, don't add anything else just try this. Attach the folder as well as I have forgotten to add that.

Comment: im getting the same error when I tried your code. By "make sure that express is installed", you mean install by `npm install -g express` right? And what folder have you forgotten to add?

Comment: Folder addition to server the static files that is what I have missed. I'll have to make a folder for you now it seems.

Comment: Dude I keep getting `TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function `. I got the same thing when I tried with your code. I have done the `npm install express`

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort man. I was using an old version of express. I upgraded to 4.14.0 and I didnt get the "not a function error". I did what you said and can get the html file, but the javascript files are not getting executed. They are in the public folder along with `index.html` file(for me it's `first.html`).

Comment: I am updating the answer check.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following in your code:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.end("text");
});
```

to this:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Now, you can serve your static index.html file with this code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    // Serve the index.html file in the root directory of the website.
    res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});
```

I hope this helps. If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: I didn't know you can send `app` as parameter

Comment: If it works for you, then please choose the answer as the correct one and let me know if it doesn't work for you :)

Comment: I get `sendFile()` is not a function error. Anyway, I used `app.use(express.static)` and loaded the html. But the angularjs and other controller javascript files aren't being executed. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks your issue is with all the static assets.

In application server like *express* you have 3 different kind of elements to serve:

1. static content: this is all *html*, client side *js*, *css*, images and so on
2. server side templates or views, are documents you assemble with some sort of templating library like *handlebars* or *jade* to produce *html*
3. api that provide data in *xml* or more common *json* format

Your issue is how to serve a static part.

You should add to the static folder of your *express* app the folder where you build your *angular* app.

Not just the *index.html* you need the client side *.js*, *.css* and all images the page require.

**UPDATE:**

[Here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) you could find the *express* documentation about static content.

**UPDATE:**

When you add a static folder to the *express* middleware, you should be able to access your file directly.

For example, if you have 2 files: `$project/static/main.js` and `$project/static/js/my-lib.js`, you should use the following urls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/main.js
http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/my-lib.js
```

Considering you're executing the node http server on localhost on port 3000.

If you provide a specific path to access the static content, then you have to rewrite your url so.

If you use a line like:

```
app.use('/staticFolder', express.static('staticFolder'));
```

Than the urls to the mentioned files will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/staticFolder/main.js
http://127.0.0.1:3000/staticFolder/js/my-lib.js
```

Also pay attention to the path you provide to express.

You should give a proper path, and it's always safer to use absolute paths:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'staticFolder'));
```

or

```
app.use('/staticFolder', express.static(__dirname + 'staticFolder'));
```

Comment: how do i send even the javascript files that are needed for the html. i created a staticFolder with all the html and angularjs and controller.js. i did the `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/staticFolder"))` but still the js files are not executed. I tried to send using `sendFile()`, but I get an error saying `sendFile()` is not a function.

Comment: Did you check on the browser if you download or not the js files? And did you check your js, css and so on have the proper path and name in the html file? You could check with `curl` the specific js file to see what happens.